# Photoshop CC keeps adding blank layers to my GIf images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

Photoshop CC is adding blank frames in to the gif that I am creating from a video.  Even if I delete the blank layers or put something on them it still exports with blanks that cause the image to flicker. (Export via save for web (legacy) GIF option that Ive seen in a few tutorials.  There are 144 frames (layers), I did try with less but the speed got too fast. Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to find a solution without seeing how the animation is made. If you don't find any solution, once made, open the gif in Photoshop, delete the blank frame and export it again.